# Debugging VB.Net Service, but getting Source Not Available

Tags: vb.net, service

I've been googling and trying different things, but I can't seem to figure out a way to debug my service :(

Typically I just use NLog to debug, but the service doesn't seem to want to create log files :(  So - I need to debug step-by-step, if possible.

I have used VS to attach to the process (can only do that with no program/solution loaded into VS)... but it says 'Source Not Available'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to debug a service is to run it as a non-service. In the following example, use `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(New serviceclassname)` to run as a service, or the dim and runConsole lines to run as a normal process. `Do While True` is ugly, but it works for debugging.

```
Shared Sub main()

System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(New serviceclassname)

' use these two lines to debug (instead of the one above)
'Dim ps As New serviceclassname
'ps.runConsole(Nothing)

End Sub

Sub runConsole(ByVal args() As String)
' This is only used for console debugging (even though nothing goes to the console)
Call OnStart(args) ' onStart Override -- if you need it.
Console.ReadLine()
Do While True
  Loop
Call OnStop()
End Sub
```